# A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled (useEffect)

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

### Problem

I am making an API call and then setting fields data once data has been fetched but the problem is it shows me the error (the title of this post). Now, I know that it error is for an input whose value is undefined but I am unable to find when does the value is undefined

### Code

Here is my Input field inside the render.

```
 <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Company"
            name="company"
            value={company}
            onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e)}
          />
```

Here is it's an initial value

```
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    company: ""
  });
 const {
    company
  } = formData;
```

and here is my useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.onFetched();

    setFormData({
      company:
        props.loading || !props.profile.company ? "" : props.profile.company,
    });
  }, [props.loading]);
```

formData contains many values, but to keep things simple, I pasted only company here.
props.onFetched() is the API call to fetch the data and store it in Redux state.

Answer (score -1):

I see a few problems with this.  First this error
`A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled (useEffect)` 
doesn't mean that your value is undefined.  It means your component is trying to change the input to an uncontrolled input.

Second, if `props.loading` is set by a redux saga/thunk, etc when you call `props.onFetched()` and you don't have any limits or verification in place it will create an infinite loop in your `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.onFetched();

    setFormData({
      company:
        props.loading || !props.profile.company ? "" : props.profile.company,
    });
  }, [props.loading]);
```

Third, you really shouldn't `setState` based on props.  If your input component needs the value of `props.profile.company` just use that prop directly.  Like this:

```
 <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Company"
            name="company"
            value={props.profile.company}
            onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e)}
          />
```

Comment: In useEffect, you can see I added props.loading as a condition for rerendering so that's no issue.
Using props.profile.company directly or through props is basically the same thing and I tried that as well but it's not working

Comment: You added `props.loading` as a dependency for `useEffect` but that means `useEffect` will run any time `props.loading` changes.  Which is why I said if it is controlled by `props.onFetched()` it will create an infinite loop.  

Also, using it directly as props vs setting and controlling state based on props is not the same thing and is actually considered a react anti pattern.